# DIV not expanding with content - used methods (min-height, overflow:hidden,clearing div..none worked :-( )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sorry if I am asking a redundant question but I tried to use almost all options given in this website and being a beginner may be I am struggling to use them to my leverage, here is the fiddle I created for my code(added several answers), I am just trying to fit in "Add Answers(Optional)" into the "tab-content" div but it doesn't seem to expanding with the content and "Add Answers" label is overshooting. Can someone just suggest what is going wrong? It would be great help...

http://jsfiddle.net/83PTq/2/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Polls</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">tab2</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Content for each tab is decided -->
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        <!-- To add answer options -->
        <form action="ask_question" class="answer_options" method="POST">
            <textarea name="question" class="question_textarea" type="text" placeholder="Your query, please ?"></textarea>
            <div class="add_answer_label">Add Answers(optional)</div>
            <div class="answers_textboxes">
                <table id="dataTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Tada</div>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', serif;
    line-height: 1.0
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height:100%;
}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
    background: none;
    color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
    background: #DFF5B0;
    color: #222;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.clear {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
.tab-content.current {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #DFF5B0;
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:1%;
}
.question_textarea {
    background: white;
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    font: 9pt Consolas;
    overflow: hidden;
}
form.answer_options {
    width:754px;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    background-color:#DFF5B0;
    padding:5px;
}
.answer_options .form label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top:2px;
    width:auto;
}
.answer_options .form input {
    width:100px;
}
.answer_options label {
    color:#444;
    width:48px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top:2px;
}
form.answer_options label.optional {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top:2px;
    color: #A3A3A3;
}
form.answer_options label.obinfo {
    float:right;
    padding:3px;
    font-style:italic;
}
form.answer_options input {
    width: 140px;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
form.answer_options input.long {
    width: 247px;
    color: #505050;
}
form.answer_options input.short {
    width: 40px;
    color: #505050;
}
form.answer_options input[type=radio] {
    float:left;
    width:15px;
}
form.answer_options label.gender {
    margin-top:-1px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width:34px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:19px;
}
form.answer_options input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    height: 18px;
}
form.answer_options input[type=password] {
    height: 18px;
}
form.answer_options input[type=button] {
    background:#9b1515;
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
}
form.answer_options input[type=button]:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#d85353;
}
form.answer_options .submit {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background: #9b1515;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(1, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)));
}
form.answer_options .submit:hover {
    background:#505050;
}
form.answer_options .submit:active {
    background:#ccc;
    color: #000;
}
form.answer_options input[type=text].small {
    height: 18px;
    width:30px;
}
form.answer_options input[type=checkbox] {
    width:14px;
    margin-top:4px;
}
form.answer_options select {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    color: #505050;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.post_query {
    height: 39px;
    left: 760px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 274px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.answers_textboxes {
    height: 39px;
    left: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 288px;
    width: 144px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.add_answer_label {
    height: 39px;
    left: 335px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 293px;
    width: 163px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.add_answer_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 289px;
}
.polls_tab {
    background:#DFF5B0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the fun world of HTML & CSS.

As jmore pointed out in his answer, the problem you faced was due to `position:absolute` which caused the element(s) to be taken out of the DOM flow. If you haven't had a chance yet, take a look at this MDN article that explains how position works. As you probably saw from our comments, it's an important concept to understand :)

MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

What you're trying to accomplish can be done a couple ways (as jmore pointed out), but the easiet way is to wrap your elements and then float the wrapper to the right. Using your mark up, you'll see that I wrapped the two divs in a container div, `additionalAnswersWrapper`.

```
<div class="additionalAnswersWrapper">
    <div class="add_answer_label">Add Answers(optional)</div>
    <div class="answers_textboxes">
        <table id="dataTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once you've wrapped your divs, you'll want to just `float` that element right.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/83PTq/4/

I wanted to take the time and point out a few other things that will help you as you continue learning.

- You should avoid using tables for layout. Tables are for tabular data, so using it to wrap your input is bad practices.
- There's a concept of web design called "responsive design". While I won't get into responsive design too much (it's beyond the scope of this question), there is an idea that your page should work across all devices. By hardcoding `widths` (for instance, the textarea), you've constrainted the element. You COULD use media queries to change the width, but it's much easier to let the `parent` take care of that.

Hopefully this answer was helpful.

Comment: Yes, the article was really useful infact tried drilling down more to use "float" and "position" in an appropriate way and figured the same thing which you did with the fiddle, Thanks :-). Also, I have removed the table usage for this purpose and now, using DIVs instead, sorry for the delay in response..

Answer (score -2):

it's because you are using `absolute` positioning which breaks the element out of the flow of the document. Positioning things is bad practice and should be a last result. Get rid of that and use something like `float` or `display: inline-block`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83PTq/3/)

```
.answers_textboxes {
  height: 39px;
  width: 144px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.add_answer_label {
  height: 39px;
  width: 163px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: I'm curious - why do you say positioning things is bad practice? If you understand the concept of positioning and how they work, positioning is very powerful.

Comment: besides the fact that it's lazy, it can create more problems then needed (look at this example right here, this is so simple and absolute positioning caused the element not to be recognized by the height of the parent). Sometimes it's needed and that's fine, but most of the time it's not. If anything were to change, or elements were added you would have to go back and readjust all of your positions.

Comment: Just to clarify - it's lazy to use positioning incorrectly. In addition, it creates more problems, when used incorrectly or when the developer doesn't fully understand the spec. Again, there's nothing wrong with positioning, when you understand how it works.

Comment: clarify "incorrectly" then. I already said "Sometimes it's needed and that's fine, but most of the time it's not." So tell me where the argument is? In this example it was not needed, call it whatever you want - lazy, incorrect - but that's why I'm saying it's bad practice to use it in this scenario, just trying to inform a self proclaimed beginner

Comment: My issue is that you're making a blanket statement about a feature of CSS to a self-proclaimed beginner, that "positioning is bad and should be used as a last resort", when it's not.

Comment: but it is, there is no reason to use it unless you have to. I've explained a couple of reasons why, all you've said is " If you understand the concept of positioning and how they work, positioning is very powerful." I do understand it..completely. You call powerful, i call lazy, why use it if you dont have to? See my point? If you use it when it's not needed - thats bad practice

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where you're getting this "positioning is bad" stance from. I agree with Jack here-- it seems that constant use of floats and the use of inline-block is overengineering at its finest. They both aren't consistent with the natural flow of a page and introduce their own issues if used too haphazardly (example: inline-block adding extra spaces/margins). Positioning is a fine tool when used correctly, but using float and inline-block to position basic elements is like using a lawnmower to cut a piece of paper; right idea, wrong tool to do it with.

Comment: You do realize that we're basically saying the same thing, right? As you said, "there is no reason to use it unless you have to", or in other words...incorrectly? Also, I didn't clarify "incorrectly" earlier because we're looking at a question that uses position:absolute "incorrectly" ("incorrectly" in the sense, there's a better way of achieving the desired outcome)...

Comment: Using positioning to do things like: relative alignment between elements (parent/child) without hardcoding pixels, using absolute positioning for performance gains (whether it's animations, SPA and reducing reflows), offsetting an element without effecting neighboring elements (or purely visual through position: relative and top/left), or position:fixed/position:sticky to avoid using JS are all power (and very common) things, and not at all "lazy".

Comment: @SkyWookie floats and inline-blocks are overengineering? Lets say you had 2 elements side by side and you positioned them absolutely to do so, now you want to go back and make your site responsive, whats the solution? use media queries to change the values? Or float/inline-block elements that will fall below each other nicely with no additional work/code? There are much greater issues you can run into with positioning then worrying about 1 pixel of extra spacing or simply clearing floating elements with no repercussions down the road...

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. so then the only thing you're advocating for is I should have stated using absolute position in this case was bad practice, you could have came out and said that from the beginning. In any case am i wrong? It should only be used "when it has to be"...i want a parallax site...i have to use absolute positioning...i want a horizontal navigation, i dont have to use absolute positioning...

Comment: @jmore009 - In hindsight, yes. But, from your answer where you state "Positioning things is bad practice and should be a last result" and your comment "besides the fact that it's lazy", it sounds like you were referring to any positioning other than static. It's one of those things that intent would have quickly been realized face to face, but ended up as a long-winded conversation over the internet :)

Comment: The solution provided solved my problem sir, but now I have a new concern "the scroll bars" Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/83PTq/2/.                                                            Is there a way to have a expanding div without the scroll bars ? thank you so much for the learning you provided from the above comments.